# Git-publishing an Azure website with lots of NuGet dependencies

Tags: git, azure, nuget

I haven't tried anything yet (because it implies converting my project from SVN to Git) so I want to ask this earlier to evaluate possible options.

I have a web project to be deployed to Windows Azure that has lots of NuGet dependencies, currently managed by Visual Studio. I'm not hosting it on Github but I would be going to host it on a dedicated repository on my source server (parallel to SVN). Since in source control you store only code and NuGet allows you to retrieve dependencies (exactly like Maven) when you change your development workstation, I'm asking how Azure behaves when dealing with Git and NuGet dependencies.

AFAIU when you `git push` to Azure you just push source code to their branch, so they detect the incoming code, compile using .NET compiler and deploy to all load balanced web servers that host your site. But what happens if your project needs NuGet dependencies? Does Azure automatically download them for you or does compiler crash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable package restore http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages  on the solution and push it with the kudu feature as explained in this blog post 
http://blog.davidebbo.com/2012/06/introducing-open-source-engine-behind.html
hth

Comment: Actually I believe the secret lies in this page: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Customizing-deployments. I'll have a detailed look at it